# How to find implementation of native method in the library .so (Android)

Tags: ida, decompilation, android, libraries

I need to make reverse engineering of one android app.
In this app I found class with name Im2MessageNative, this class contains a lot of native methods.
For example:

```
static native long createMessageWrite(int i);
```

I tried to find an implementation of the method using the Ida Pro. To do this, I opened a tab with strings, then search for phrase "createMessageWrite", next I opened memory address and found this:

```
.rodata:00B29B29 aCreatemessagew DCB "createMessageWrite",0
.rodata:00B29B29                                         ; DATA XREF: 
.data:00DDC4CC↓o
.rodata:00B29B29                                         ; .data:00DDC4D8↓o
```

I was looking for a "aCreatemessagew", but could not find any function.

How to find the implementation of this native method?

Comment: Isn't that inside a symbol table address?

Comment: symbol table address, what do you mean? Is it a window?

Comment: I know how native code works in Android/Java, but I can't find any function, which contains Java_com_..._createMessageWrite